# Randomly Generating objects to Junit testing

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have to write a Junit test Case where i will be testing the NonNullProperty of an object.

For this i want to randomly generate a class and set properties to it. This is going to be a stub class and will be destroyed after user.

Currently i am doing this:-

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        fixture = new Copy();
        Date source;
        source = new Data();
        source.setAction("Action");
        source.setTags("Tags");
    }
```

Here Data is a Pre-Defined class that i have in my code.

Can Anyone please suggest the way forward!

Comment: What exactly do you want to generate? An **object** of type `Data` with randomly filled fields?

Comment: You should consider using something like Mockito (http://site.mockito.org/) - will help you create mocks for classes/objects/methods etc

Comment: I want to create any random object and set my desired property to it.

Comment: By "any random object", do you mean any of the objects you are using in your code? Or literally **any** object that is available at runtime? The latter would probably mean you need to do reflection, if there is no library for it.